Why does chlorine have a higher electron affinity value than fluorine?
Why does chlorine have a higher electron affinity value than fluorine? Since this periodic property tends from the bottom up (in the group), the logic would be that the fluorine is the element with more electronic affinity, in addition this property tends from left to right (in the period), everything tends to fluorine. Respectively fluorine has a value of 328, while chlorine has a value of 349. Another important thing is that the fluorine has number Z = 9, and chlorine Z = 17. If we see as we go down in the group, the atomic radius increases, the distance between the nucleus and the last electron increases, then, it is easier to add an electron, less energy is needed.

This question is a duplicate of: Why does chlorine have a higher electron affinity than fluorine?. Answers there aren't great though.
